# SQLite pragma resets to default

Tags: sqlite

I am using a SQLite database in `WAL` mode. My issue that `*.db-wal` file is growing up to enormous sizes, so I'm trying to limit it by setting following settings:

```
PRAGMA wal_autocheckpoint = 100;
PRAGMA journal_size_limit = 2000000000;
```

I tried doing it via SQLiteStudio: i set them, then i verify them using

```
PRAGMA wal_autocheckpoint;
PRAGMA journal_size_limit;
```

and see that everything was set correctly. But if then I reconnect to a database and request them once more, i get default values: 1000 and -1.

I thought that maybe the scope of these PRAGMAs is only current connection, so I tried always having one connection with these settings but it doesn't work - I've just found the `*.db-wal` file with 32 GB size.

What's the scope of these PRAGMA statements? Does they affect only current connection? Does `journal_size_limit` limit journal for only one connection or for all connections combined? Or maybe there are any other reasons for my settings being reset?

Comment: Most pragmas only affect the current connection, yes, including those.

Comment: As a general rule, unless it sets a values in [database header page](https://sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#the_database_header), it's not persistent.

Comment: @Shawn so if I have 10 connections, journal_size_limit = 2000000000 (2GB), total size of the journal can grow up to 20GB?

Comment: It shouldn't unless you have some really big transactions.

Comment: @Shawn I don't have big transactions (no more then 60 rows inserts), but saw my journal grow up to 32GB.

Comment: Have you read https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html#avoiding_excessively_large_wal_files and seen if any of the other situations apply? Checkpoint starvation, maybe?

Comment: @Shawn Yes, i did, and I think it is indeed a checkpoint starvation, because I have a lot of clients constantly reading and writing small amounts of data. I think, the solution can be manuallly calling wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE) from time to time for each connection, but I want to somehow make it automatic via database settings.